# Implementing a failover heartbeat mechanism in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, failover

this may sound like a strange long-winded question...I'm implementing a failover mechanism.

This is written in C# .NET 4.5 Console application using SQL Server.

**My requirements in order of priority:**

1. Only one instance of the program can be running at a time (NEVER two),
2. If one instance fails/hangs, start the other instance (on a separate VM) as soon as possible but ensure the original one stops (to meet requirement #1 above).

**What I did:**
Before updating the database during normal operations, the program will:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
Check to ensure the database's MasterName table shows it is still master,
Modify Database
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The procedure above implements requirement #1 but ensuring that the program is still the Master before modifying the database.

To implement requirement #2, the active program issues a heartbeat to the db and the program which is not the master (the slave) checks these timestamps.

If the Slave notices the timestamp has not been updated in 2X seconds, it will write its own name in the database MasterName table and take over.

Here's the rub: In the above flow,

1) If the Master hangs for a minute (say Windows is indexing or something) after it has checked to ensure it is still Master, and in that time, ServerB takes over, ServerA won't know that ServerB took over because it is in the middle of its TRANSACTION and will complete.

I could "Lock some table".

Ok, say I lock:

```
LOCK MasterNameTable
BEGIN TRANSACTION
Check to ensure the database's MasterName table shows it is still master,
Modify Database
COMMIT TRANSACTION
UNLOCK MasterNameTable
```

Now, if ServerA crashes, or hangs for a really long time, ServerB can't take over since it is locked out.

This feels like a catch-22.   I have to believe this has been implemented millions of times in the past and there probably is some standard out there.   I'd appreciate any pointers.

EDIT 1:  Providing more details:

This is a .NET 4.5 Console Application. I have two instances of it running on two separate VMs so that if one fails, the other can "take over".

This is an algorithmic stock trading application so it would be bad to have two running at the same time (duplicate trading) and it would be bad if there were a timespan when it was not running (missing opportunities and missing ways to "get out")...   All failover mechanisms I have researched to-date involve a timespan when both "could" be running at the same time (however short) so this is the only solution I have found to-date that prevents this.

Comment: When you say if one fails start the other service, I assume you can stop the other process as well? Can you use lock and `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 2000x milliseconds` so if a process can't get the lock for that period you'll get an error meaning the other process is taking longer than it should and kill it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your setup? From what I understood you have two programs written in .NET, both have ability to write to the same databse BUT only one program is allowed to write at any given time. You are trying to implement a method to deteect when one program hangs and start the other?

Comment: I have added edits.   I like the timeout idea.  Does SQL support that?   I have no way to kill the process unless I write another Windows application / Service to do so.

Comment: This is indeed a difficult problem to solve. Have you considered writing your application to utilize Windows Clustering?

Comment: Yes but to my knowledge, Windows Clustering (Hyper-V Failover) only accounts for VM failures, not application hangs.